# How do I get a byte[] (image) from a webservice using micronaunt HttpClient

Tags: download, binary, httpclient, micronaut, micronaut-client

I am porting a Grails 3.1 library for using some internal webservices to Grails 4.0.   One of the services provides an image of a requested employee upon request.  I am having difficulty implementing the (micronaut) HttpClient code to process the request - specifically to get a proper `byte[]` that is the returned image.

A simple curl command on the command line works with the service:

```
curl -D headers.txt -H 'Authorization:Basic <encodedKeyHere>' https:<serviceUrl> >> image.jpg
```

and the image is correct.  The header.txt is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
content-type: image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 27 Aug 2019 20:05:43 GMT
x-ratelimit-limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 99
x-ratelimit-remaining: 99
X-RateLimit-Reset: 38089
x-ratelimit-reset: 15719
Content-Length: 11918
Connection: keep-alive
```

The old library uses the `groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder` and simply does:

```java
http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.BINARY) {
            uri.path = photoUrlPath
            uri.query = queryString
            headers.'Authorization' = "Basic $encoded".toString()
            response.success = { resp, inputstream ->
                log.info "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"                
                return ['status':resp.status, 'body':inputstream.getBytes()]
            }
            response.failure = { resp ->
                return ['status':resp.status, 
                        'error':resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase, 
                         body:resp.getEntity().getContent().getText()]
            }
        }
```

so returning the bytes from an inputStream.  This works.

I've tried several things using the micronaut HttpClient, both with the low level API and with the declarative API.

A simple example with the declarative API:

```java
    @Get(value='${photo.ws.pathurl}', produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
    HttpResponse<byte[]> getPhoto(@Header ('Authorization') String authValue, 
                                  @QueryValue("emplId") String emplId)
```

And than in the Service:

```java
    HttpResponse<byte[]> resp = photoClient.getPhoto(getBasicAuth(),emplId)
    def status = resp.status()            // code == 200 --> worked 
    def bodyStrOne = resp.getBody()       // nope: get Optional.empty 
    // Tried different getBody(class) -> Can't figure out where the byte[]s are   
    // For example can do:
    def buf = resp.getBody(io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf).value // Why need .value?
    def bytes = buf.readableBytes()       // Returns 11918 --> the expected value
    byte[] ans = new byte[buf.readableBytes()]
    buf.readBytes(ans)    // Throws exception: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
```

This "works" but the returned String looses some encoding that I can't reverse:

```java
   // Client - use HttpResponse<String>
   @Get(value='${photo.ws.pathurl}', produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
   HttpResponse<String> getPhoto(@Header ('Authorization') String authValue, 
                                  @QueryValue("emplId") String emplId)
```

```java
   // Service 
   HttpResponse<String> respOne = photoClient.getPhoto(getBasicAuth(),emplId)
   def status = respOne.status()                  // code == 200 --> worked 
   def bodyStrOne = respOne.getBody(String.class) // <-- RETURNS DATA..just NOT an Image..or encoded or something
   String str = bodyStrOne.value                  // get the String data  
   // But these bytes aren't correct
   byte[] ans = str.getBytes()                    // NOT an image..close but not.
   // str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) or any other charset doesn't work
```

Everything I've tried with the ByteBuf classes throws the `io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0` exception.

Any direction/help would be greatly appreciated.

Running:

```
    Grails   4.0 
    JDK      1.8.0_221 
    Groovy   2.4.7
    Windows  10
    IntellJ  2019.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be Grails bug.

---

Add this line into `logback.groovy`:

```java
logger("io.micronaut.http", TRACE)
```

Then you should see that the body was not empty but finally it ends with error `Unable to convert response body to target type class [B`. See the trace:

```
2019-09-11 11:19:16.235 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Status Code: 200 OK
2019-09-11 11:19:16.235 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Content-Type: image/jpeg
2019-09-11 11:19:16.235 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Content-Length: 11112
2019-09-11 11:19:16.237 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Accept-Ranges: bytes
2019-09-11 11:19:16.237 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Response Body
2019-09-11 11:19:16.237 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : ----
2019-09-11 11:19:16.238 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : ���� C   
...
2019-09-11 11:19:16.241 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : ----
2019-09-11 11:19:16.243 TRACE --- [ntLoopGroup-1-4] i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient        : Unable to convert response body to target type class [B
```

But when you try the same in standalone Microunaut application (add `<logger name="io.micronaut.http" level="trace"/>` into `logback.xml`) the result is different:

```
09:02:48.583 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 200 OK
09:02:48.583 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Type: image/jpeg
09:02:48.589 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 23195
09:02:48.590 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
09:02:48.590 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
09:02:48.612 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ���� C���
...
09:02:48.620 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
```

Micronaut trace has no error.

---

Here is an example of declarative HTTP client which downloads random image from https://picsum.photos web site:

```java
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client

@Client('https://picsum.photos')
interface LoremPicsumClient {
    @Get(value = '{width}/{height}', produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
    HttpResponse<byte[]> getImage(Integer width, Integer height)
}
```

And Spock unit test for it:

```java
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

@MicronautTest
class LoremPicsumClientSpec extends Specification {
    @Inject
    LoremPicsumClient client

    void 'image is downloaded'() {
        given:
        def output = Paths.get('test')

        when:
        def response = client.getImage(300, 200)

        then:
        response.status == HttpStatus.OK
        response.getBody().isPresent()

        when:
        Files.write(output, response.getBody().get())

        then:
        Files.probeContentType(output) == 'image/jpeg'
    }
}
```

In Micronaut the test passes and an image is saved into the *test* file. But in Grails the test fails because HttpClient is not able to convert the response bytes into `byte` array or better into anything else then `String`.

Comment: Well I tried this and it still does not work.  In the mean time I got it all working using the 'io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.4' library:

` try {
            ans = HttpBuilder.configure {
                ignoreSslIssues execution
                request.headers['Authorization'] = getBasicAuth()               
               request.uri = theUrl
               request.uri.query = [huid: huid]
           }.get()`

Comment: I turned on trace by adding a logback-test.xml file (I'm using Grails) and using the HttpResponse<byte[]> client I get 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present 

on the response.getBody().get() even though the status is 'Ok' 
The trace says it's on (ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [io.micronaut.http.client] to TRACE) but I'm not getting any additional info from it that I can see anywhere.

Comment: The one thing different between your example and mine is my Photo service uses basic Auth - could that be causing the issue !?

Comment: Sorry, I tried that only in Micronaut for the first time (as I'm using only Micronaut) and there was no problem with that. Now I tried the same in Grails 4 and also my small example is failing the same way as yours. From my point of view it must be a Grails bug. I updated the answer and added the error message from trace in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using this implementation:

```
@Client(value = "\${image-endpoint}")
interface ImageClient {

  @Get("/img")
  fun getImageForAddress(
    @QueryValue("a") a: String
  ): CompletableFuture<ByteArray>
}
```

works fine for us.

When I use the HttpResponse I get an error as well, couldn't make it work with that.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#serverIO) propose to send bytes via input stream but I didn't manage to make it work. The most brittle thing that HttpClient should **Consume** bytes but Server should **Produce**.

```
@Get(value = "/write", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
HttpResponse<byte[]> write() {
    byte[] bytes = "test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return HttpResonse.ok(bytes); // 
}
```